# CSS button that auto adjusts to the window size

Tags: html, css

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vvbG.jpg) is what it looks like on pc. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs3H1.jpg) is what it looks like on mobile. I want the buttons on mobile to be smaller (auto-adjusted to the screen size).

This is the HTML and CSS for the page:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            .container {
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .container img {
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
                right: 0;
                top: 0;
            }
            .container .btn {
                position: absolute;
                top: 45%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                background-color: #555;
                color: white;
                font-size: 20px;
                padding: 12px 24px;
                border: none;
                cursor: pointer;
                border-radius: 5px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .container .btt {
                position: absolute;
                top: 45%;
                left: 24%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                background-color: #555;
                color: white;
                font-size: 20px;
                padding: 12px 24px;
                border: none;
                cursor: pointer;
                border-radius: 5px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .container .btc {
                position: absolute;
                top: 45%;
                left: 76%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                background-color: #555;
                color: white;
                font-size: 20px;
                padding: 12px 24px;
                border: none;
                cursor: pointer;
                border-radius: 5px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .container .btn:hover {
                background-color: white;
                color: black;
            }
            .container .btt:hover {
                background-color: white;
                color: black;
            }
            .container .btc:hover {
                background-color: white;
                color: black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="some img" alt="" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1660" />
            <a href="some ref" <button class="btn">ER DU ARRANGØR?</button></a>
            <a href="some ref" <button class="btt">ER DU MARKEDSFØRER?</button></a>
            <a href="some ref" <button class="btc">KONTAKT OSS!</button></a></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

I'm assuming, if this is possible, that the solution would be to change the `.container .btx` for the buttons. I can't find a way to do this.

Comment: I would suggest changing sizing of the font and button elements from pixels to either rem or em units as this would give you some adjustment "for free" just by being on the smaller device/resolution.

Comment: I think the button is sized based on the font size of 20px.  You could use a responsive font size like this - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_text.asp

Comment: You have invalid HTML; you can't place a button inside an anchor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definitely look into [**media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries).

They allow you to work on different screens defined by various parameters (width, height, orientation).

```
@media (max-width: 800px) { 
    //your code goes here
}
```

I think this is what you're looking for.

Also take a look at [**viewport width and height**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Relative_length_units) units (`vh` and `vw`) that allow you to resize elements according to the size of the window.

```
div{ 
    height: 50vh;//50% of the viewport (window) height
    width: 40vw;//40% of the viewport (window) width
}
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend linking to higher quality resources like MDN rather than W3Schools. I would also recommend fleshing out this answer a bit more to provide a direct application of your answer to the question, rather than simply pointing OP to a CSS feature that might work.

Comment: Please put a working sample with you answer only then will the answer be complete.

Comment: @TylerH is W3Schools that bad ? I often find interesting examples on there.

Comment: @Nasta They are not as bad as they used to be, but they still are considered a low quality resource. They take a long time to update wrong or outdated content, artificially inflate their search results (they pay a lot of money to Google to appear near the top), along with other such dubious business practices.

Comment: @TylerH Edited with MDN links, thanks for the insight

Answer (score 2):

As answered in the above comment, you should definitely check out `@media` query and `vh` and `vw`. I'll also recommend you to take a look at [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

---

I tweaked your code a bit with `vh`, `vw`, `calc()` with some minor modifications and this is what I came up with. Adjust the values in `width` and `calc()` to suit your need. Yeah, I don't use `@media` here.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .container img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    button {
      position: absolute;
      top: 45%;
      width: 23vw;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      font-size: calc(0.5rem + 1vw);
      padding: 12px 24px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 5px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .container .btn {
      left: 50%;
    }
    
    .container .btt {
      left: 24%;
    }
    
    .container .btc {
      left: 76%;
    }
    
    .container .btn:hover {
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .container .btt:hover {
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .container .btc:hover {
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="some img" alt="" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1660" />
    <a href="some ref"><button class="btn">ER DU ARRANGØR?</button></a>
    <a href="some ref"><button class="btt">ER DU MARKEDSFØRER?</button></a>
    <a href="some ref"><button class="btc">KONTAKT OSS!</button></a></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I found I had to tweak the padding as well.

Comment: You're always welcome! Try using relative units e.g. em, rem, vh, vw, % etc as often as possible. This will make properties adjust to the screen dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

I found of my old css codes for responsive.
Yes you should use media, something like:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .quotesBox {
        font-size: 19px;
    }
    .ftrLinks li a {
        padding: 0px 15px;
    }
    .socialLinks li {
        padding: 0px 10px;
    }
    .socialLinks li a img {
        width: 37px;
        height: 37px;
    }
}
```

I hope it can help you, just change for your needs